Xcode Gitignore Firebase Packages?
In the process of writing an App employing 'Source Control'.
The App uses Firebase.
What I don't want to do is push the Firebase Packages to my Github repository.
I understand that I need to use 'gitignore' but don't know how to do this and hoping someone can steer me in the correct direction.


make a .gitignore file in your project root directory, then add the file or directory in. Regular match is supported.

Thanks LF-DevJourney, all sorted now. Cheers.
